# Sabre get one way itineraries

Tags: php, sabre

I'm actualy using InstaFlights REST API to get sepecifics itineraries and this works perfectly.

My  problem is ,how can I get the **one way** itineraries details from origin , destination and range dates given as parameters.

Which API can be used to achieve this?
is there any example using **SOAP or REST** with PHP can helps us

Answer (score 1):

InstaFlights does not support one way itineraries at the moment.

You can use the Bargain Finder Max (BFM) API for that (in both, REST and SOAP flavors)

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max